# How can I mock structure method in same structure method in Golang?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I have troubles with mocking.. I have same code:

```
type OtherInterface interface {
   Do() error
}
type MyInterface interface {
   MethodA() error
   MethodB() error
}
type MyStruct struct {
  OtherStruct OtherInterface
}
func(s *MyStruct) MethodA() error {
  return s.MethodB()
}
func(s *MyStruct) MethodB() error {
  return s.OtherStruct.Do()
}
```

And test code of MethodB:

```
type MockOtherStruct struct {
  Do_Error error
}
func (t *MockOtherStruct) Do() error {return t.Do_Error}


TestMyStruct_MethodB(t *testing.B) {
  expectedError = nil
  mos := &MockOtherStruct{
    Do_Error: nil
  }
  ms := MyStruct{
   OtherStruct: mos,
  }
  err := ms.MethodB()
  if err != expectedError {
    t.Fatal(err)
  }      
}
```

But how can I test MethodA?

Yes, I can also mock OtherStruct and use not mocked MethodB, but in big structs I can have many fields with other structs, but use one internal method..

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is: You construct an instance of `MyStruct` and call `MethodA` and check the result. That's what you do with `MethodB` already. To control the returned value you handcrafted the instance of MyStruct by setting its fields. And that's it. If you want deterministic output you have to control the input and the OtherStruct field _is_ and input to Method{A,B}. If you have more fields you have to control all which are inputs to the functions under test.

Comment: Note that Go does not force you to stuff any functionality into **methods**. Maybe you could use more functions? Maybe even OtherInterface could be replaced by a simple function argument?

Comment: @Volker thank you for your comment. I don't agree with that this case is not problem. There is simple example. In real code, my struct have 5-10 fields with different interfaces, and when I'm testing methodA, which call methodB, methodB have difficult logic. MethodB can call multiple fields' methods, also this class methods, but I need to mock only methodB. Why I need mock other structures and methods? It's not easy way. You are testing structure, but I need to  testing structure's methods.